# keyboard event not loading in cpp for sdl

Tags: c++

I am trying to make it my screen print `hello` when I click the `a` key... And switch images when I press the `2` key... however when I do,  nothing happens, I'm not sure why... it does not give me an error for some weird reason... if you have any ideas please let me know in the comments below. I have listed the code there!

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* WindowSurface = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* image1 = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* image2 = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* currentImage = nullptr;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("sdl Window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, 
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    WindowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    image1 = SDL_LoadBMP("Red_sheet_full_2.bmp");
    image2 = SDL_LoadBMP("Red_sheet_fullA.bmp");
    currentImage = image2;
    bool isRunning = true;
    SDL_Event ev;
    while (isRunning)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0);
        {
            if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                isRunning = false;
            else if (ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch (ev.key.keysym.sym)
                    case SDLK_a:                         
                        printf("hello");
                break;
                switch (ev.key.keysym.sym)
                    case SDLK_2:
                        currentImage = image1;
                break;
            }
        }
     
        SDL_BlitSurface(currentImage, NULL, WindowSurface, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    }
    
    SDL_FreeSurface(image1);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image2);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
   
    currentImage = image1 = image2 = nullptr;
    window = nullptr;
    
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `switch` statement. The `break` is outside the `switch` so, if the first event you receive is not an `SDLK_a`, it will break out of the `while` loop before printing `hello` and exit.

Here's a simplified version of what's happening: https://godbolt.org/z/9eEcEYGhj

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        char c{'p'};
        switch (c)
            case 'a':
                std::cout << "a\n";
        break;  // exits without printing anything
        switch (c)
            case 'b':
                std::cout << "b\n";
        break;
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

You have different ways to fix it.

One would be to write the `switch` statement in a proper way: https://godbolt.org/z/99MohaTMx

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        char c{'a'};
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'a':
                std::cout << "a\n";  // forever prints "a\n"
                break;
            case 'b':
                std::cout << "b\n";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }                     
}
```

Another one, just for your current implementation, would be to use an `if-else if` instead of a `switch`.